# Wildcards in autcomplete API

Tags: autocomplete, geocoding, here-api

I use HERE autocomplete API (autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com) to get suggestions.

Let's say I'd like to search for "budaörsi" street, house number: 11, so I make a request as "budaörsi 11". This gives good result, however, when I search for "budaör 11" there is no suggestions at all.

Is it possible to use wildcards somehow to make this search phrase to work: "budaör* 11"?

Most of the time users do not type the whole street, just some characters and the house number, and they do not understand why they do not get suggestions.

Or do I need to use another HERE API for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete basically "guess" the result from user's input, so if I try to input "budaör" it will give me some options such as "Hungary, 2040, Budaörs" or "Hungary, Budapest, Budaörsi út", I think the problem here is if you are not following the sequence of typing input, and just more like a copy-paste of "budaör 11", it doesn't fit the scenario of Autocomplete.

Perhaps you can try regular geocode, but you need to give more context, such as city names, it will greatly help you getting the result, for example you can search "budaör 11, budapest, hungary" you can get 2 results of "Budapest körút 11, Gyula 5700, Hungary" and "Budapest út 11, Veszprem 8200, Hungary".

[image]